# write xpath for randomly generated name

Tags: java, xpath

I trying to write `xpath` for a randomly generated name or number(which is usually the project name), which produces `xpath` like below:

```
//*[@id="job_10"]/td[3]/a  
//*[@id="job_11"]/td[3]/a     
//*[@id="job_12"]/td[3]/a
```

`10`,`11`,`12` are the project numbers and can be words too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* Yes, please clarify your question, by showing input, expected output, what you've tried so far, and how the word "random" applies, as opposed to "dynamic", aka an input value.

Comment: If you're "trying to write xpath" then it's presumably because you have some goal in mind for what that xpath should accomplish, and it might be useful if you shared that goal with us. Otherwise a perfectly reasonable answer would be "42" (which is a valid XPath).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below `XPath` expression:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, "job_")]/td[3]/a
```

This should allow to match elements with `id` attribute which starts with `job_` and ends with string or number...whatever

Comment: Hi Anderson. Tried that,that selects the first project on the page. I wanted to click on the last one(which is the newly added one).

Comment: try `(//*[starts-with(@id, "job_")]/td[3]/a)[last()]`

Comment: @sharansai: If you'd post a [mcve] and a clear requirement, Andersson wouldn't have to guess and could have solved your problem ten times by now.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to select an html element?  If so, you might be better of using a css selector instead of xpath.

If you have the html as a String, you can use JSoup to parse the document, then use a css selector to find the last row in the table.

```
String htmlDocument = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlDocument);
Element anchor = doc.select("tr[id^=job_]:last-child td:nth-child(3) a");
```